# How to connect mongoDB in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Such a problem that when I try to simply connect mongoDB in react

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class App extends Component{

  componentDidMount(){
    const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

    const client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://dafu4k:****@cluster0.jd26aac.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

    const start = async () => {
    try{
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Connected')
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)  
    }
  }
  start();
 }

  render(){
    
  return (

    <>
    <h1>Home page</h1>
    </>
  )

  }
}
```

Errors of the same type appear in the browser itself

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\DaFu4\OneDrive\Рабочий >стол\mongotest\mongo-test\node_modules\ip\lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
> - install 'os-browserify'
>   If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
>   resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

They differ in that the last line has different keys (`timers`,`crypto`,`http`, etc.)

I watched how to connect mongoDB to react, everywhere they used a certain mongoose along with mongoDB, but I can’t understand, maybe it’s required to connect to react, or am I still doing something wrong? (in normal js everything works fine, the code has not changed)

`src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mongo-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can connect your react application directly to MongoDB database. You connect to the database using MongoDB NodeJS driver _or_ Mongoode ODM APIs in a NodeJS app. And a react app can get data from a NodeJS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**We can not connect React JS to MongoDB because things don’t work like this.**
First, we create a react app, and then for backend maintenance, we create API in node.js and express.js which is running at a different port and our react app running at a different port. for connecting React to the database (MongoDB) we integrate through API.

Check this link:

[1]: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-mongodb-with-reactjs/#:~:text=First%2C%20we%20create%20a%20react,MongoDB](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-mongodb-with-reactjs/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20we%20create%20a%20react,MongoDB))%20we%20integrate%20through%20API.

Comment: Anyone else having issues with the last 2 steps? Mine appear blank...

Answer (score 0):

React is not communicating directly with MONGODB (via mongoose). It interacts with nodejs/express which is the one to communicate with MONGODB.

The explanation for the steps are presented in what I find to be the clearest form, in [MERN STACK TUTORIAL](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial) (MERN = Mongodb, Express, React and Nodejs),
especially as the most essential part doesn't exist in Geeks4Geeks' tutorial (the part where they show you an example code of index.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const cors= require("cors")

app.use(cors());

const PORT = 2020;

const MongooseConnect =
  "mongodb link to profile";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(express.json());

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  brend: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },

  context: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

});

const Products = mongoose.model("Products", productSchema);


app.post("/add", async (req, res) => {

  const newpProdct = new Products({

    ...req.body,

  });

  await newpProdct.save();

  res.send(newpProdct);

});

app.get("/add", async (req, res) => {

  const data = await Products.find();

  res.send(data);

});


app.delete("/add/:id", async (req, res) => {

  const { id } = req.params;

  await Products.findByIdAndDelete(id);

  res.send("product has been deleted");

});


app.put("/add/:id", async (req, res) => {

  const { id } = req.params;

  const updatedProduct = await Products.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body 
});

});


mongoose.connect(MongooseConnect).then(() => {

  console.log("DB CONNECTED");

});

app.listen(PORT, () => {

  console.log("App running");

});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with the help of supporting information

Answer (score -1):

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors= require("cors")
app.use(cors());
const PORT = 8080;
const MongooseConnect =
  "Mongodb";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(express.json());

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  detail:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

const Products = mongoose.model("Products", productSchema);


app.post("/add", async (req, res) => {
  const newpProdct = new Products({
    ...req.body,
  });
  await newpProdct.save();
  res.send(newpProdct);
});


app.get("/add", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await Products.find();
  res.send(data);
});


app.get ("/add/:id", async (req,res)=>{
    const {id} = req.params
    const target = await Products.findById(id)
    res.send(target)
})


app.delete("/add/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  await Products.findByIdAndDelete(id);
  res.send("product has been deleted");
});


mongoose.connect(MongooseConnect).then(() => {
  console.log("DB CONNECTED");
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("App running");
});
```

Comment: Sir, this is NodeJS + Express, not React. You probably means that we need to create a API to feed react with data.